# i would like to merge this array such that its one array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
```

i have decalered the array before the for loop

```
$sample=array();
```

I am Fetching database data which is in form of eg 5,6,2 i had imploded the before and stored them

```
$myseats= $db->displaySeats($showtime_id);
foreach ($myseats as $key) {
    $bookedseats= $key['seats_booked'];
```

Exploding the values to $test variable

```
    $test=explode(",", $bookedseats);
    array_push($sample,$test);
}
print_r($sample) ;
?>
```

the problem is I am getting this output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22 
                        [1] => 26 
                        [2] => 27 
                        [3] => 37 
                        [4] => 38 
                        [5] => 41 
                    ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 30 
                        [1] => 31 
                        [2] => 32 
                    ) 
    )
```

that is two arrays inside an array..the database has this two entries which am using a test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing arrays into an array, use `array_merge(`)  to place all these items into a single array as part of your loop

```
$sample = [];
foreach ( $rows as $bookedseats ){
    $test=explode(",", $bookedseats);
    $sample = array_merge($sample, $test);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_merge`
[PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)